# Why isn't my caption updating in my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, ejs

I'm trying to update a post's caption with a form on an `ejs` file. I'm not sure if something is wrong with my routes or my `ejs` page. Right now after submitting to the form it just redirects to the index page without actually updating the caption column in the table of my database.

Here are the `update` routes:

```
app.get('/update', (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.locals.alerts);
  res.render('update', { alerts: res.locals.alerts });
});

// update caption
app.put('/update', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  console.log('--- PUT route ---');
  db.post.update({
    caption: req.body.caption
  }, {
    where: { id: req.body.id }
  }).then(() => {
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})
```

And here is the `update.ejs`:

```
<form action="/update?_method=put" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="caption" placeholder="New Caption:" id="updatePostText" >
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="postSubmit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you check database update query.Is it all correct?

Comment: Yes, nothing is being updated in my database

Comment: once check the update query in the backend